# Why did reanimated Itachi lose eye vision after using Izanami?

Tags: naruto

As I understand, any physical part of a reanimated person cannot be destroyed. It will be regenerated automatically within a short time. Then, why did Itachi lose his eyesight after using Izanami? He should've got the eye back quickly as he was a reanimated person. Or, he could've damaged his own eye with a kunai, so that he would get a fresh Mangekyo Sharingan.

Answer (score 8):

> Q. *Any physical part of a reanimated person cannot be destroyed.*

The eye was not destroyed at all. It just lost its light forever. As stated in the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanami) (emphasis mine)

> It is a genjutsu which affects the target through physical sensations shared between them and the user. Like its counterpart, in exchange for the temporary ability that it grants the user, **the Sharingan with which Izanami is cast is rendered blind and loses its light forever.**

---

> Q. *It will be regenerated automatically within a short time.*

Since the eye was never destroyed, it did not regenerate.

---

> Q. *He could've damaged his own eye with a kunai, so that he would get a fresh Mangekyo Sharingan.*

The light of the eye was already lost. Even if Itachi were to destroy it with his own kunai, the regenerated eye would still have been the one without its light.

Also, it should be noted that Itachi did not want to stay in the living world anymore, as he had no more attachments with the living (after telling the truth to Sasuke). Therefore, Itachi would never have tried it at all in the first place.

Comment: Here is a scenario, What if itachi is blasted into pieces by a paper bomb? Will he get Sharingan back along with his other body parts?

Comment: He'll get the eye back, but it would be without light. Since the eye has already lost its light, the light would not come back. The eye would, however, re-generate, just like all the other body parts.

Comment: One last question, is losing eye light not physical damage? like nerve disconnection

Comment: Not always. Let me just quote few lines about vision loss from wikipedia. *Vision loss or visual loss is the absence of vision where it existed before, which can happen either acutely (i.e abruptly) or chronically (i.e over a long period of time). It may be caused by media opacities, retinal disease, optic nerve disease, visual pathway disorders, or functional disorders, or it may be in fact an acute discovery of chronic visual loss.* Thus you can becomes blind by either damaging the retina or something and because of using Izanami as well! :P

Answer (score 1):

The effect of using Izanami is that you lose **use** of an eye - that is, the user becomes blind.

The eye is there - it has not been lost. Itachi is simply now blind in that eye.